# Why does my rsync command not recurse into directories?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, raspbian

I am trying to use rsync to backup a website on my raspberry pi, but when I specify include and exclude it is not recursing into subdirectories.  I use the following command:

```
rsync -rva html/ /media/pi/DEC6-5E68/html/ --include '.htaccess' --include '*.html' --include '*.php' --exclude '*'
```

But I only am backing up the upper level and not recursing, despite the 'r' option.  I think I have a basic misunderstanding of linux wildcards.   It does recurse if I omit any include or exclude arguments.

Comment: My answer has not been accepted, so maybe it's not enough. Can I get some feedback? How can I help you more?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't had a chance to test it yet.  But I will accept your answer by virtue of it being quite definitive.

Comment: I didn't mean to rush you; just thought maybe the problem is not entirely solved. To be clear: it's not about reputation points I get for accepted answer, it's about solving the problem. If it turns out after testing that the solution is not enough, please leave me a comment. And don't hesitate to unaccept if appropriate, I believe you can do this anytime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever a subdirectory is encountered, it gets excluded by the `--exclude '*'` statement and `rsync` doesn't descend.

This behavior is mentioned in the manual, with a solution. From `man 1 rsync`:

> Note that, when using the `--recursive` (`-r`) option (which is implied by `-a`), every subcomponent of every path is visited from the top down, so  include/exclude patterns get applied recursively to each subcomponent’s full name (e.g. to include `/foo/bar/baz` the subcomponents `/foo` and `/foo/bar` must not be excluded). The exclude patterns actually short-circuit the directory traversal stage when `rsync` finds the files to send. If a pattern excludes a particular parent directory, it can render a deeper include pattern ineffectual because `rsync` did not descend through that excluded section of the hierarchy. This is particularly important when using a trailing `*` rule. For instance, this won’t work:
>
> ```
> + /some/path/this-file-will-not-be-found
> + /file-is-included
> - *
> ```
>
> This fails because the parent directory `some` is excluded by the `*` rule, so `rsync` never visits any of the files in the `some` or `some/path` directories.  One solution is to ask for all directories in the hierarchy to be included by using a single rule: `+ */` (put it somewhere before the `- *` rule), and perhaps use the `--prune-empty-dirs` option. […]

Note this part of the manual uses the syntax of the `--filter` (`-f`) option where `+` is like `--include` and `-` is like `--exclude`. The advised rule `+ */` may appear in your command line as `--include '*/'`. Quoting is very important, it prevents `*/` from being expanded by the shell.

For completeness this is what the manual says about the useful `--prune-empty-dirs` option:

> `-m`, `--prune-empty-dirs`
> This option tells the receiving `rsync` to get rid of empty directories from the file-list, including nested directories that have no non-directory children.  This is useful for avoiding the creation of a bunch of useless directories when the sending `rsync` is recursively scanning a hierarchy of files using include/exclude/filter rules.
>
> […]

So your command may be

```
rsync -rmva html/ /media/pi/DEC6-5E68/html/ \
      --include '*/' \
      --include '.htaccess' \
      --include '*.html' \
      --include '*.php' \
      --exclude '*'
```

You can omit the destination (`/media/pi/DEC6-5E68/html/` in your case) to make `rsync` only *list* what would be copied. This way you can verify if my command is what you need.